# How to run TestNG AND JUnit tests with Maven-3 under Jenkins without loosing reporting

Tags: junit, jenkins, maven-3, testng

After adding TestNG tests to our Jenkins test job reports would no longer be produced.  I removed the TestNG tests and dependencies and reports started to be produced again.  How can I run both TestNG and JUnit tests with Maven-3 under Jenkins with reporting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your pom configuring surefire as recommended [here](http://solidsoft.wordpress.com/2013/03/12/mixing-testng-and-junit-tests-in-one-maven-module-2013-edition/)?
(pom plugin example copied below)
You should confirm that both test libraries are being run at the command line as well as from jenkins using the *test* goal.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${surefire.version}</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Nope, I hadn't.  We've since removed all the TestNG bits, but this is something we didn't have so I've marked your answer as correct.  Thanks for the great link.